# Changing class using classlist.add not working

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to change the name of the class 'popup' to 'popup active' when I click some button. The code isn't working please help me out.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <button class="button">click me</button>
    <div class="popup"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

js.js:

```
const but = document.querySelector('.button');
const pop = document.querySelector('.popup');

but.onclick = () => {
    pop.classList.add('active');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your script is executed before your DOM is built, place it after your elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button class="button">click me</button>
    <div class="popup"></div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Or defer it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script defer src="js.js"></script>
    <button class="button">click me</button>
    <div class="popup"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

3. You could also watch for your DOM being loaded without changing your HTML:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const but = document.querySelector('.button');
const pop = document.querySelector('.popup');

but.onclick = () => {
    pop.classList.add('active');
}

});
```

Comment: @KartikeyaChauhan you are welcome, mate. also you could upvote my answer (the arrow up) so i would be motivated to help you in the future. i've upvoted your answer so you know can do that, thanks

Comment: You don't need `defer` on the script tag, the window event listener is enough.

Comment: @JosephWebber if DOMContentLoaded is used the HTML stays the same, sorry i wasn't clear about that in the answer. these are 3 different solutions

Answer (score 1):

there is a small conflict in the place of  `script` Here is a corrected code

```js
const but = document.querySelector('.button');
const pop = document.querySelector('.popup');

but.onclick = () => {
    pop.classList.add('active');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button class="button">click me</button>
    <div class="popup"></div>
     <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What square are you referring to?

Comment: what the sense to duplicate another answer?

Comment: I did not repeat the answer and the one who has the best is the one who will get an acceptable answer 